# How to I install xscope (X11) on osx?

Tags: macos, homebrew, autoconf, automake, xlib

I want to debug my xlib based c++11 program using xscope on OSX 10.8.4.  Not the designer tool, but the one talked about in this link.

http://jklp.org/public/profession/papers/xscope/paper.htm

Is this possible?  How do I go about getting xscope working on osx?  I use brew and have automake and autoconf installed.  I downloaded the xscope-1.4 source from freedesktop at

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xscope/

There is no existing `Makefile` or `./configure`, but only a `configure.ac`, so I'm guessing I'm supposed to use `autoconf`, but when I run that, I get:

```
configure.ac:38: error: must install xorg-macros 1.8 or later before running autoconf/autogen
configure.ac:38: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
```

These seem to return nothing

```
brew search | grep macros
brew search | grep xorg
```

Comment: I figured out that xscope needs xtrans.  I downloaded the xtrans source since I could not find it as a brew formula, but autoreconf -i also wants xorg-macros.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install `xorg-macros`, which are part of the X.org project.
your favourite web-search engine will quickly reveal that you can download them from[http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/xorg/util/macros.git](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/util/macros).

btw, on Debian (which you are not using, but still), the xorg-macros are part of the `xutils-dev` package.